# How to create a new record in a MySQL table as copy of the previous with diff changes only?

Tags: mysql

I'm building an endpoint for a third-party service who POSTs data to my server.  To cut down on bandwidth, the third-party only sends changes from the previous record's fields.

So imagine the table looks like this, with the very first record:

```
+----+------+------+-------+-------+-------+
| id | item | size | color | state | count |
+----+------+------+-------+-------+-------+
|  1 | 0001 |  500 | blue  | on    |    12 |
+----+------+------+-------+-------+-------+
```

The next data that might be sent to me would just be `item: 0001, color: green, count: 15` and I would have to insert a record so the table looks like the following:

```
+----+------+------+-------+-------+-------+
| id | item | size | color | state | count |
+----+------+------+-------+-------+-------+
|  1 | 0001 |  500 | blue  | on    |    12 |
|  2 | 0001 |  500 | green | on    |    15 |
+----+------+------+-------+-------+-------+
```

Notice how the `size` and `state` fields remain unchanged, but are copied down to the next row.  (`id` is simply an auto-incrementing key)

Further, this is unique per `item` identifier.  So if I get a few different `item` records the table looks like this:

```
+----+------+------+-------+-------+-------+
| id | item | size | color | state | count |
+----+------+------+-------+-------+-------+
|  1 | 0001 |  500 | blue  | on    |    12 |
|  2 | 0001 |  500 | green | on    |    15 |
|  3 | 0002 |  700 | white | off   |    42 |
|  4 | 0001 |  500 | red   | off   |     9 |
|  5 | 0003 |  300 | black | on    |    66 |
+----+------+------+-------+-------+-------+
```

Then I get this message: `item: 0002, size: 100` the table would look like this:

```
+----+------+------+-------+-------+-------+
| id | item | size | color | state | count |
+----+------+------+-------+-------+-------+
|  1 | 0001 |  500 | blue  | on    |    12 |
|  2 | 0001 |  500 | green | on    |    15 |
|  3 | 0002 |  700 | white | off   |    42 |
|  4 | 0001 |  500 | red   | off   |     9 |
|  5 | 0003 |  300 | black | on    |    66 |
|  6 | 0002 |  100 | white | off   |    42 |
+----+------+------+-------+-------+-------+
```

Is there a way I can do this solely with MySQL?  A stored procedure or something similar?

Answer (score 0):

`INSERT INTO ... SELECT` may get you reasonably far here.  Consider the following insert statement:

```
INSERT INTO yourTable (item, size, color, state, count)
SELECT '0001', t1.size, 'green', t1.state, 15
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT item, MAX(id) AS max_id
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY item
) t2
    ON t1.item = t2.item AND
       t1.id   = t2.max_id
WHERE t1.item = '0002';
```

I assume here that your backend technology would be receiving the `item` which you want to insert, along with the new column values.

Note that if executing the above via a prepared statement, then the query would look more like this:

```
INSERT INTO yourTable (item, size, color, state, count)
SELECT ?, t1.size, ?, t1.state, ?
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT item, MAX(id) AS max_id
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY item
) t2
    ON t1.item = t2.item AND
       t1.id   = t2.max_id
WHERE t1.item = ?;
```

You would then bind values for the placeholders, i.e. this query could potentially be used for every insert request.

A slight alternative to this would be to just execute a full select, followed by an insert, inside a single transaction.  But if you can do this in a single query, then it is likely preferable to two queries.

Comment: At the moment my unique identifier is the `item` column, as you can see in my examples above.  I am not storing the `id` for the previous `item` record.  I could add it to the `items` table (which I do have), but wouldn't that defeat the purpose of making it a single query, since I'd need to look up that ID?

Comment: @Bing So are you looking for the max ID record for each item?

Comment: Yes, to update the latest record per unique `item` identifier.

Comment: @Bing I updated my answer to use the latest record for each item.